# Load image for RecyclerView with Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a problem when I load a image in a `RecyclerView` using Glide. When I use a url it works but when I get the url from a array it doesn't work.

```
public class HistorialAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistorialAdapter.HistorialViewHolder> {
private List<Incidencia> items;
private MenuActivity context;
private View v;
private String url;

public static class HistorialViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imagen;
    public TextView nombre;
    public TextView estado;
    public TextView fecha;
    public View v;


    public HistorialViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.v=v;
        imagen = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        estado = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado);
        fecha = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }

}

public HistorialAdapter(Context context, List<Incidencia> items) {
    this.context = (MenuActivity) context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public HistorialViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardincidencia, viewGroup, false);
    return new HistorialViewHolder(v);
}


    @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final HistorialViewHolder viewHolder, int pos)      {
    Log.v("url ", items.get(pos).getImage());
    url="http://thumbs.subefotos.com/0f309f78c5dc93515bf95c984728269do.jpg";
    Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
            //.load(url) -> it works
            .load(items.get(pos).getImage()) ->it doesn't work
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(viewHolder.imagen) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    super.setResource(resource);
                }
            });
    viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(pos).getTitle());
    viewHolder.estado.setText(items.get(pos).getStatus());
    viewHolder.fecha.setText(items.get(pos).getFecha());

    ....More code...

}
```

This is the url log

```
V/url: http://thumbs.subefotos.com/026b968faedb576d0675a3e17bbf9fe6o.jpg
V/url: http://thumbs.subefotos.com/0f309f78c5dc93515bf95c984728269do.jpg
V/url: http://thumbs.subefotos.com/026b968faedb576d0675a3e17bbf9fe6o.jpg
V/url: http://thumbs.subefotos.com/0f309f78c5dc93515bf95c984728269do.jpg
```

How can I see that I have the correct url on my List?

Comment: post the constructor code of your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using trim in my url when I debug I get this string:

```
"http://thumbs.subefotos.com/026b968faedb576d0675a3e17bbf9fe6o.jpg            "
```

this was the problem